# How to manage uploaded files before corresponding RESTful request comes

Tags: rest, web

Assume that data model is a user profile. Each record has `name`, `age`,  `portrait` and so on, where `portrait` is an image.

On front-end editing page, I want the portrait image uploaded immediately after selected so the final submit won't be time-consuming.

```
open front-end editing page 
    |
    |
edit some fields
    |
    |
select an image for portrait ---.
    |                           |
    |                           |
    |                 uploading...may take a while
    |                           |
grab a cup of coffee            |
    |                           |
    |                           |
edit other fields               |
    |                           |
    |                   upload finished
    |                           |
    |---------------------------'
    |
 submit                          
    |                           
    |
 respone
```

The `submit` step is actually sending a POST request to the backend with something like `{ name: 'John', age: 20, portrait: 'what should be here?' }`. The question is what should be in the `portrait` field of the request data?

I come up with an idea but don't know if there is a better one:
Backend returns a token representing the image resource as response to the image upload. Then frontend send the data with that token set to `portrait` field.

And there is another question: what if the user cancelled the editing? The uploaded file still exists on server's storage and needs to be cleaned up. Maybe I can send the token when the user clicked a "Cancel" button. But what if user just leave the editing page without clicking the "Cancel" button?

Is there a best practice of doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul has the right idea on the identifier of the uploaded document.

> And there is another question: what if the user cancelled the editing? The uploaded file still exists on server's storage and needs to be cleaned up. Maybe I can send the token when the user clicked a "Cancel" button. But what if user just leave the editing page without clicking the "Cancel" button?

Even if the user does click the cancel button, that signal may not actually be delivered to your server (unreliable network).

You need something on the server that can identify abandoned images, and a facility that removes them.  You could have the server do this cleanup itself, or you could expose resources in your api that allow it to be controlled remotely.